# JUnit5 test with LiveData doesn't execute subscriber's callback

Tags: android, junit, mockito, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

**Background:**

I have a simple application that fetches movie list using rests API call. The project structure is given below,

```
Activity -> ViewModel -> Repository -> ApiService (Retrofit Interface)
```

1. The activity subscribes to a **LiveData** and listens for events changes
2. The **ViewModel** hosts the **MediatorLiveData** observed by the activity. Initially the **ViewModel** sets a `Resource.loading(..)` value in **MediatorLiveData**.
3. The **ViewModel** then calls the repository to get the movie list from **ApiService**
4. The **ApiService** returns a **LiveData** of either `Resource.success(..)` or `Resource.error(..)`
5. The **ViewModel** then merges **LiveData** result from **ApiService** in **MediatorLiveData**

**My Queries:**

Inside the unit test, only the first emit `Resource.loading(..)` is made by **MediatorLiveData** from **ViewModel**. The **MediatorLiveData**  never emits any data from the repository.

**ViewModel.class**

```
private var discoverMovieLiveData: MediatorLiveData<Resource<DiscoverMovieResponse>> = MediatorLiveData()

fun observeDiscoverMovie(): LiveData<Resource<DiscoverMovieResponse>> {
        return discoverMovieLiveData
    }

fun fetchDiscoverMovies(page: Int) {

        discoverMovieLiveData.value = Resource.loading(null) // this emit get observed immediately 

        val source = movieRepository.fetchDiscoverMovies(page)
        discoverMovieLiveData.addSource(source) {
            discoverMovieLiveData.value = it // never gets called
            discoverMovieLiveData.removeSource(source)
        }
    }
```

**Repository.class**

```
fun fetchDiscoverMovies(page: Int): LiveData<Resource<DiscoverMovieResponse>> {
        return LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(
            apiService.fetchDiscoverMovies(page)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .map { d ->
                    Resource.success(d) // never gets called in unit test
                }
                .onErrorReturn { e ->
                    Resource.error(ApiErrorHandler.getErrorByThrowable(e), null) // // never gets called in unit test
                }
        )
    }
```

**Unit Test**

```
@Test
fun loadMovieListFromNetwork() {
        val mockResponse = DiscoverMovieResponse(1, emptyList(), 100, 10)
        val call: Flowable<DiscoverMovieResponse> = successCall(mockResponse) // wraps the retrofit result inside a Flowable<DiscoverMovieResponse>
        whenever(apiService.fetchDiscoverMovies(1)).thenReturn(call)

        viewModel.fetchDiscoverMovies(1)

        verify(apiService).fetchDiscoverMovies(1)
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(apiService)

        val liveData = viewModel.observeDiscoverMovie()
        val observer: Observer<Resource<DiscoverMovieResponse>> = mock()
        liveData.observeForever(observer)

        verify(observer).onChanged(
            Resource.success(mockResponse) // TEST FAILS HERE AND GETS "Resource.loading(null)" 
        )
    }
```

**Resource** is a generic wrapper class that wraps data for different scenario e.g. loading, success, error.

```
class Resource<out T>(val status: Status, val data: T?, val message: String?) {
.......
}
```

**EDIT: #1**

For **testing purpose**, I've updated my rx thread in repository to run it on main thread. This ends up with a **Looper not mocked** exception.

```
fun fetchDiscoverMovies(page: Int): LiveData<Resource<DiscoverMovieResponse>> {
            return LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(
                apiService.fetchDiscoverMovies(page)
                    .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .map {...}
                    .onErrorReturn {...}
            )
        }
```

In test class,

```
@ExtendWith(InstantExecutorExtension::class)
class MainViewModelTest {

    companion object {
        @ClassRule
        @JvmField
        val schedulers = RxImmediateSchedulerRule()
    }

    @Test
        fun loadMovieListFromNetwork() {
        .....  
       }
}
```

}

**RxImmediateSchedulerRule.class**

```
class RxImmediateSchedulerRule : TestRule {

    private val immediate = object : Scheduler() {
        override fun createWorker(): Worker {
            return ExecutorScheduler.ExecutorWorker(Executor { it.run() })
        }
    }

    override fun apply(base: Statement, description: Description): Statement {
        return object : Statement() {
            @Throws(Throwable::class)
            override fun evaluate() {
                RxJavaPlugins.setInitIoSchedulerHandler { immediate }
                RxJavaPlugins.setInitComputationSchedulerHandler { immediate }
                RxJavaPlugins.setInitNewThreadSchedulerHandler { immediate }
                RxJavaPlugins.setInitSingleSchedulerHandler { immediate }
                RxAndroidPlugins.setInitMainThreadSchedulerHandler { immediate }

                try {
                    base.evaluate()
                } finally {
                    RxJavaPlugins.reset()
                    RxAndroidPlugins.reset()
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**InstantExecutorExtension.class**

```
class InstantExecutorExtension : BeforeEachCallback, AfterEachCallback {

    override fun beforeEach(context: ExtensionContext?) {
        ArchTaskExecutor.getInstance().setDelegate(object : TaskExecutor() {
            override fun executeOnDiskIO(runnable: Runnable) {
                runnable.run()
            }

            override fun postToMainThread(runnable: Runnable) {
                runnable.run()
            }

            override fun isMainThread(): Boolean {
                return true
            }
        })
    }

    override fun afterEach(context: ExtensionContext?) {
        ArchTaskExecutor.getInstance().setDelegate(null)
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you add the code of  `liveData.observeForever`? And instead of using an ArgumentMatcher, you might be better of using an ArgumentCaptor and compare the actual content of what Resource.loading is returning.

Comment: In the repository, `apiService.fetchDiscoverMovies()` is subscribed on a io scheduler, which means that the Flowable won't send notification synchronously on the same thread. So check if you have properly configured the test schedulers.

Comment: @SanlokLee Good observation. I changed the thread but can't get the LiveData work with Rx. Please check my updated question.

Comment: @second observeForever is a built in method from androidx.lifecycle

Comment: Can you post a minimal project with that setup at github? I'll have a look.

Comment: @azizbekian Thanks for your interest. Please have a look here https://github.com/prokash-sarkar/AndroidX

Comment: @FallingIntoInfinity, I've just checked out the project, seems like your test is passing. Any concerns that you have at this point?

Comment: @azizbekian I'm expecting a "Resource.success(..)" in verify(observer).onChanged(Resource.success(...)) but the LiveData only emits "Resource.loading(null)" from ViewModel ignoring the "Resource.success(..)" from repository.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you specify `RxImmediateSchedulerRule` won't work for JUnit5. If you place a breakpoint in `apply()` method you'll see that it is not being executed.

Instead, you should create an extension as specified [here](https://zaglab.io/blog/junit5-and-rx-testscheduler/):

```
    class TestSchedulerExtension : BeforeTestExecutionCallback, AfterTestExecutionCallback {

        override fun beforeTestExecution(context: ExtensionContext?) {
            RxJavaPlugins.setIoSchedulerHandler { Schedulers.trampoline() }
            RxJavaPlugins.setComputationSchedulerHandler { Schedulers.trampoline() }
            RxJavaPlugins.setNewThreadSchedulerHandler { Schedulers.trampoline() }
            RxAndroidPlugins.setMainThreadSchedulerHandler { Schedulers.trampoline() }
        }

        override fun afterTestExecution(context: ExtensionContext?) {
            RxJavaPlugins.reset()
            RxAndroidPlugins.reset()
        }

    }
```

Then apply `TestSchedulerExtension` in test class's annotation as such:

```
    @ExtendWith(value = [InstantExecutorExtension::class, TestSchedulerExtension::class])
    class MainViewModelTest {

        private val apiService: ApiService = mock()
        private lateinit var movieRepository: MovieRepository
        private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel

        @BeforeEach
        fun init() {
            movieRepository = MovieRepository(apiService)
            viewModel = MainViewModel(movieRepository)
        }

        @Test
        fun loadMovieListFromNetwork() {
            val mockResponse = DiscoverMovieResponse(1, emptyList(), 100, 10, 0, "", false)
            val call: Flowable = Flowable.just(mockResponse)
            whenever(apiService.fetchDiscoverMovies(1)).thenReturn(call)

            viewModel.fetchDiscoverMovies(1)

            assertEquals(Resource.success(mockResponse), LiveDataTestUtil.getValue(viewModel.discoverMovieLiveData))
        }

    }
```

Now the test will pass. Now you have tested, that observer has been dispatched with the expected value.

---

From another angle: is this a unit test? For sure it's not, because in this test we are interacting with 2 units: `MainViewModel` and `MovieRepository`. This more obeys to "integration test"'s term. Had you mocked out `MoviesRepository`, then this will be a valid unit test:

```
@ExtendWith(value = [InstantExecutorExtension::class, TestSchedulerExtension::class])
class MainViewModelTest {

    private val movieRepository: MovieRepository = mock()
    private val viewModel = MainViewModel(movieRepository)

    @Test
    fun loadMovieListFromNetwork() {
        val mockResponse = DiscoverMovieResponse(1, emptyList(), 100, 10, 0, "", false)
        val liveData =
            MutableLiveData>().apply { value = Resource.success(mockResponse) }
        whenever(movieRepository.fetchDiscoverMovies(1)).thenReturn(liveData)

        viewModel.fetchDiscoverMovies(1)

        assertEquals(Resource.success(mockResponse), getValue(viewModel.discoverMovieLiveData))
    }

}
```

Note, `MovieRepository` should be declared as `open` alongside with `fetchDiscoverMovies()` in order to be able to mock it. Alternatively you can consider using [`kotlin-allopen`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html) plugin.

Comment: Thanks a lot. At this point, I'm curious to know 1. In unit test If we mock "movieRepository" there will be no interaction with the apiService. Is that okay? 2. What's the best practice to write unit test along with an interaction test? Should I write 2 test function for each of them? Or should I place them in a different directory?

Comment: 1. Unit testing means testing of the units. In your case the unit that you want to test in the `ViewModel` class, which means that any other dependency should be stubbed. In your case `ViewModel` doesn't even know about the existence of `ApiService` class, so it's perfectly okay to *not* have interaction with `ApiService`. Interacting with `ApiService` is wrong (if you are covering `ViewModel` with unit tests).

Comment: 2. I'm not sure what you mean by _"interaction"_. Maybe you meant _"integration"_. Integration testing would mean testing of multiple components together. For example performing action `foo` results in a value saving in `SharedPrefs`, then you verify that `SharedPrefs` has in fact that value retained. In your case there is an API layer, which means that you can have a look at [`retrofit mock`](https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-mock) library.

Comment: Everything is clear now. Should I place the unit test along with integration classes inside the /test folder? Is there any convention?

Comment: `androidTest` corresponds to espresso tests *only*, hence all other tests should be located at `test` directory.

Comment: This answer is awesome, but, i tried and it didn't work for me. I added:


`RxAndroidPlugins.setInitMainThreadSchedulerHandler { Schedulers.trampoline() }`


in the `beforeTestExecution(context: ExtensionContext?)` method, and it's working now.


@azizbekian the link(zaglab.io) that you specified has expired, but, your answer helped a lot, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I think all you need to do is change

```
val call: Flowable<DiscoverMovieResponse> = successCall(mockResponse)
```

to

```
val call: Flowable<DiscoverMovieResponse> = Flowable.just(mockResponse)
```

And **make use of the [LiveDataUtil](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/test-common/java/com/android/example/github/util/LiveDataTestUtil.kt) class** from the architecture components google sample. So you'll need to copy/paste that into your project.

So at the end of the day your new test would look like this **(assuming all the associations and mocks are setup correctly at the top of the test class)**. Also you're using an **InstantExecutorExtension** like azizbekian showed you above.

```
@Test
fun loadMovieListFromNetwork() {
    val mockResponse = DiscoverMovieResponse(1, emptyList(), 100, 10)
    val call: Flowable<DiscoverMovieResponse> = Flowable.just(mockResponse)
    whenever(apiService.fetchDiscoverMovies(1)).thenReturn(call)

    viewModel.fetchDiscoverMovies(1)

    assertEquals(Resource.success(mockResponse), LiveDataTestUtil.getValue(viewModel.discoverMovieLiveData))
}
```

If that test passes, it means you were able to successfully observe the results of a network request and return a successful response.