# ViewModel Junit Test fails in case when i use Junit5 and Rxjava. Method getMainLooper in android.os.Looper not mocked

Tags: rx-java2, android-testing, junit5, android-viewmodel

I am trying to wrote test case for my view model and I am using junit5 along with mockito. The issue is my test case is always failing it gives me this error

```
    at android.os.Looper.getMainLooper(Looper.java)
    at io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers$MainHolder.<clinit>
```

Now I did a lot of research on this issue and found out that this is due to Rxjava scheduler as it is not able to run on the background thread I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56422249/junit5-test-with-livedata-doesnt-execute-subscribers-callback) link and did the required step so after that my view model looks like this

**MainViewModelTest.kt**

```
@ExtendWith(value = [InstantExecutorExtension::class,TestSchedulerExtension::class])
class MainViewModelTest {


    @Mock
    private lateinit var repository: GithubRepository

    private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel

    @Before
    fun init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
        viewModel = MainViewModel(repository)
    }

    @Test
    fun testNull(){
        assertThat(viewModel.observeTrendingRepository(), notNullValue())
        verify(repository, never()).makeRequestForTrendingRepo(anyBoolean())
    }

    @Test
    fun fetchTrendingGitHubRepository_emptyDbFirstTimeCase(){

        `when`(repository.makeRequestForTrendingRepo(anyBoolean()))
            .thenReturn(Flowable.just(Resource.Loading(listOf())))

        viewModel.fetchTrendingGitHubRepository(false) // this is where it fails

        assertEquals(Resource.Loading<List<Repository>>(listOf()),LiveDataTestUtil.getValue(viewModel.observeTrendingRepository()));
    }
}
```

Here are the InstantExecutorExtension and TestSchedulerExtension that take care of live data and Rxjava respectively.

```
package com.rajat.zomatotest.utils

import androidx.arch.core.executor.ArchTaskExecutor
import androidx.arch.core.executor.TaskExecutor
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.AfterEachCallback
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.BeforeEachCallback
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext

class InstantExecutorExtension : BeforeEachCallback, AfterEachCallback {

    override fun beforeEach(context: ExtensionContext?) {
        ArchTaskExecutor.getInstance().setDelegate(object : TaskExecutor() {
            override fun executeOnDiskIO(runnable: Runnable) {
                runnable.run()
            }

            override fun postToMainThread(runnable: Runnable) {
                runnable.run()
            }

            override fun isMainThread(): Boolean {
                return true
            }
        })
    }

    override fun afterEach(context: ExtensionContext?) {
        ArchTaskExecutor.getInstance().setDelegate(null)
    }

}
```

```
package com.rajat.zomatotest.utils

import io.reactivex.android.plugins.RxAndroidPlugins
import io.reactivex.plugins.RxJavaPlugins
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.AfterTestExecutionCallback
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.BeforeTestExecutionCallback
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext


class TestSchedulerExtension : BeforeTestExecutionCallback, AfterTestExecutionCallback {

    override fun beforeTestExecution(context: ExtensionContext?) {
        RxJavaPlugins.setIoSchedulerHandler { Schedulers.trampoline() }
        RxJavaPlugins.setComputationSchedulerHandler { Schedulers.trampoline() }
        RxJavaPlugins.setNewThreadSchedulerHandler { Schedulers.trampoline() }
        RxAndroidPlugins.setMainThreadSchedulerHandler { Schedulers.trampoline() }
    }

    override fun afterTestExecution(context: ExtensionContext?) {
        RxJavaPlugins.reset()
        RxAndroidPlugins.reset()
    }

}
```

I couldn't understand why is it giving me error, I have correctly added **TestSchedulerExtension.kt** so this should work!!

Comment: This should work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56422249/junit5-test-with-livedata-doesnt-execute-subscribers-callback?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: i have already tried the above link but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same problem, and I found that the way to fix this was by using

```
RxAndroidPlugins.setInitMainThreadSchedulerHandler { scheduler }
```

instead of

```
RxAndroidPlugins.setMainThreadSchedulerHandler { scheduler }
```

In this [link](https://medium.com/@peter.tackage/overriding-rxandroid-schedulers-in-rxjava-2-5561b3d14212) you will find more information.